# Outer approximation of Borel sets by disjoint union of sets of the form $(\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n} ]$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Original question: $f$ is a Borel measurable function on $(0,1]$ such that $\int_{(\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}]} f = 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \le k \le n-1 $ . Then to show that $f$ is zero almost everywhere with respect to Borel measure on $(0,1]$ .

I want to try proving that $\int_E f = 0$ for every Borel measurable $E \subset (0,1]$. For that I want to approximate Borel sets from above by finite disjoint unions of sets of the form $(\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n}] $

Is this possible? If so can someone provide me with a hint? I know I can't approximate from below because set of irrationals can't be  approximated from below by these kind of sets.

Comment: You can use the fact that $(0,1]=\cup (\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}]$, and for integrable $f$ and disjoint measurable sets $A_i$, $\int_{\cup A_i } f = \sum_{i} \int_{A_i} f$

Comment: @NazimJ I am not sure what to do with that. Here $f$ is not necessarily non-negative. Are you assuming something like that?

Comment: no assumptions other than $f$ is integrable, it's true for general complex valued $f$ and follows Dominated Convergence theorem.  My hint was for the answer to the original question by the way.  But if find a way to approximate $E$ from above, then you can also use the  hint to conclude $\int_{E} f=0$